# search for a string in a line after another string in a previous line

Tags: regex, xml, awk, sed

I reached my goal but it is neither elegant nor robust:

```
Port=`grep -A5 "web gui" $Conf|awk -F[\:\<] \\
'/address/{print $3}'`
```

`$Conf` is the xml file I have to parse, searching for the `Port` number through I can communicate with this machine/software. `web gui` string appears only once in the file. As you see `address` appears before, after and between the `web` tags. Her position, as well as the number of other lines may vary inside the tags. My code is weak because it relies on grep's -A5. I guess I could increase it, but I don't how to specify EOF to grep, then end the awk action with `...;exit;}`. I'm not sure because I don't know if it would work the way as `grep -m1`.
I think there is surely something oneliner best and shorter with awk. I first thought using awk with RS="" or some special character here meaning EOF to treat the file as a single line, then use FS=["web","address"] but I'm stuck.

```
    ....    
    <address>auto</address>
    <idle>false</idle>
    <someKey>false</someKey>
    <otherkey>0</otherkey>
    <maxSpeed>0</maxSpeed>
    <maxHeat>0</maxHeat>
</machine>
<web gui="on" tls="on" log="off">
    <user>****************</user>
    <address>127.0.0.1:1234</address>
    <password>***************</password>
    <key>*********************</key>
    <skin>turquoise</skin>
</web>
<OtherTag></OtherTag>
<options>
    <Listenaddress>https://someHost.net</Listenaddress>
    ...
```

Any help welcome
Thank you

Comment: you're better off using an xml aware tool.

Comment: Are you running the command on Linux? Do you have access to xsltproc? It would be simple and clean to use an XSLT transformation to output the port number.

Comment: To complete your question [edit] it to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions to parse XML is the wrong tool for the job. You might get it to work on a limited number of test cases, but someone will always be able to come up with a way of writing the XML that breaks your code. (There's a theoretical reason for that based on the fact that the XML grammar is recursive.)

Parse the XML using a proper XML parser, and search it using XPath.

Comment: Yes !!! Very effective, tested in my laptop. Although in my case, even I didn't require awk, awk was my solution (see below). Because Xpath depends on perl and `man xpath` is spartan and I didn't want to install additionnal software in this raspberry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`'s range feature

```
sed -rn '
  /<web gui=.*>/,/<\/web>/{
    /<address>/s/^[^:]+:([[:digit:]]+).*$/\1/p
  }' "$Conf"
```

You can use `awk`'s range feature

```
awk -F'[:<]' '
  /<web gui=.*>/,/<\/web>/{
    if($0~/address/){print $3}
  }' ./input
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ sed -rn '/<web gui=.*>/,/<\/web>/{/<address>/s/^[^:]+:([[:digit:]]+).*$/\1/p}' ./input
1234

$ awk -F'[:<]' '/<web gui=.*>/,/<\/web>/{if($0~/address/){print $3}}' ./input
1234
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SiegeX, thanks to you and awk's **range** feature (comma between 2 patterns gives 1rst and last records to search between... but be carefull that the 1rst record do not match the second pattern too ;-) see/search awk manual for notes on **Range**) and **if** against **$0** in actions I got it work.